# A common expression that means agreeing with what everyone else said

Tags: phrases, expressions

So I wanna leave a rate my professor review and leave a comment that's pretty much consistent with what's already been said just for the sake of - in math terms - adding value for the sake of raising the average - so to speak. Haha. It's really difficult to articulate what I'm getting at but I know there's a phrase for this.

Comment: You "concurred"?

Comment: Me too-ing, ditto-ing, nodding assent, positive reinforcement, stroking, bobbleheading...

Answer (score -1):

A **yes-man**

> a person who agrees with everything that is said especially : one who
>   endorses or supports without criticism every opinion or proposal of an
>   associate or superior

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yes-man)